# Is it possible to add custom tabs to open different page layouts of single custom object?

Tags: custom-object, tab

I have created one Custom Object and 3 different page layouts for that, Now i want to open these layouts from tabs, For example - on click of Custom tab1 , first layout should open, on tab2 -layout 2 and so on. is that possible without creating Visualforce pages?

Thanks in advance,Mani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with out additional tabs through the use of record types. Even if you could do multiple tabs for a custom object, you don't have the ability to choose the page layout since this is determined by record types.

Add some record types then update the page layout mapping so each record type corresponds to the desired page layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible without creating VF page.. Because for one custom object you can create on one Custom Object Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please elaborate this question . I think , I am missing something here. 
 Page layout relates to the record of the object. When You click on object tab , it opens standard page for that object. nothing relates to layout.

You can have custom VF tab and open different pages . but remember those will be pages not layout. Thanks,